# How to build MSYS-dependent program with gcc4?

Tags: mingw, msys

MinGW comes with a gcc configured for making Windows programs. So for instance, it will not compile and link this little program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
   uid_t u = getuid(); // no such function in Microsoft library
   return 0;
}
```

This program *will* compile and link with the MSYS compiler, since the MSYS library has this function. This is how, for instance, the GNU Coreutils program `id` can obtain and print the user ID, and how `ls -l` in MinGW prints user and group IDs and so on.

The only problem is, this MSYS compiler is old: gcc 3.4.4.

Is there a nice, "canonical" way to point MinGW's gcc 4.5.2 to the right headers and libraries for compiling MSYS-based programs?

Or is that route not recommended at all; it is better to build an MSYS gcc4 from scratch, bootstrapped with MSYS gcc3?

Comment: Have you seen my answer? could it help you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the answer is "you probably don't want to do this" (hence information about it is scant). The purpose of the MSYS environment is to provide the utilities for building MinGW programs. If the given program isn't needed for this purpose, it doesn't need to be build for MSYS.

**In other words, MinGW effectively provides a cross-compiling toolchain, where the target system is the executable environment on Windows based on Microsoft's library. Utilities in the cross-compiling toolchain itself are built on MSYS, but MSYS is not available to the cross-compiled programs.**

Applications that need more of a Unix-like environment (like that enjoyed by the utilities included in MinGW) can use Cygwin. MSYS is a fork of Cygwin anyway. Like Cygwin, MSYS provides its own library. For instance, not only is `getuid` there, but if you call `stat` on a file, the `st_uid` and `st_gid` fields are filled in from information in the file security descriptor, whereas the Microsoft version of the function used by MinGW programs will leave these fields as zero. MSYS must be regarded as a separate target from MinGW, like Cygwin; converting a program that works with MinGW to MSYS is a form of porting.

In my case, the program in question already targets Cygwin, so there is probably little point in supporting MSYS as a target also unless the MSYS project wanted to pull in that program as part of the MinGW environment.